# Solr edismax, boosting according to column of document

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a solr database with shops and descriptions. I query solr to fetch me shops that include specific keywords in the shopTitle or the shopDescription.
I use edismax to boost the shopTitle over shopDescription so that when I search for a shop name and one is found it would always end up first regardless how many time it could be mentioned in another shop's description. However we also have an internal sorting indicator (score). What I am looking for is to mix this internal ranking in the document boost.

ie.

```
shop: Amazon
shopDescription: .... eBay ... mediamarkt ... ikea dishwasher
internalRanking: 250000

shop: eBay
shopDescription: .... amazon ... amazon .... ikea ... dishwasher dishwasher dishwasher
internalRanking: 180000

shop: mediamarkt
shopDescription: .... eBay .... amazon ... amazon ... dishwasher dishwasher
internalRanking: 178000

shop: Ikea
shopDescription: ... eBay ... mediamarkt ...
internalRanking: 175000

shop: dishwasher world
shopDescription: ... dishwasher ... eBay ... mediamarkt
internalRanking: 80000

shop: dishwasher masters
shopDescription: ... dishwasher ... dishwasher ... dishwasher ... dishwasher dishwasher
internalRanking: 100
```

what I am doing atm is:

```
"params": {
  "pf": "title description",
  "sort": "computed_ranking desc",
  "q": "dishwasher",
  "qf": "title^20 description^0.1",
  "defType": "edismax"
}
```

this works fine but does not include the internalRanking. How can I push it in the weights calculation so that

search for dishwasher should return the shops in the following order

```
dishwasher world (1st because: title contains keyword + highest internal ranking on the shops with title match)
dishwasher masters (2nd because: title contains keyword but has lass internal ranking than dishwasher world)
eBay (3rd because of the description)
mediamarkt (4th because of the description)
Amazon (5th because of the description)
```

but I can't figure it out... how can I mix the internalRanking (document property/column) with the document weights so that I can calibrate the order.

Answer (score 1):

solution found.

1. I should be usinf dismax and not edismax for my case
2. dismax.bf is the function. All I had to do is identify my attribute there (internal ranking)
3. my biggest mistake was that myboosting scores where too low. my internal ranking can hold values as high as 1mil. Adjusting my boost scores finally delivered the expected results!

I still love solr :)